# React ag grid trigger double click even on single cell

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

The following allows me to have the first available cell focused by default:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      editMode &&
      gridRef.current?.api &&
      ppsColumns &&
      ppsColumns.length > 0 &&
      lastSelected === undefined
    ) {
      const value = ppsColumns[0].field;

      gridRef.current.api.setFocusedCell(0, value);
    }
  }, [editMode, gridRef.current]);
```

however, I would like to trigger a double click event instead of setting a focus state which enables the user to edit the cell immediately. Is there some sort of api that allows to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use setTimeout to work around timing issues, try adjust the delay duration (100 ms in the example)

```
 useEffect(() => {
  const startEdit = () => {
    if (
      editMode &&
      gridRef.current?.api &&
      ppsColumns &&
      ppsColumns.length > 0 &&
      lastSelected === undefined
    ) {
      const firstColumnField = ppsColumns[0].field;

      gridRef.current.api.setFocusedCell(0, firstColumnField);

      setTimeout(() => {
        gridRef.current.api.startEditingCell({
          rowIndex: 0,
          colKey: firstColumnField,
        });
      }, 100); // delay in ms, adjust as necessary
    }
  };

  startEdit();
}, [editMode, gridRef.current, ppsColumns, lastSelected]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your useEffect to start editing the first cell when your conditions are met:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (
    editMode &&
    gridRef.current?.api &&
    ppsColumns &&
    ppsColumns.length > 0 &&
    lastSelected === undefined
  ) {
    const firstColumnField = ppsColumns[0].field;

    // Focusing the cell is still necessary before starting to edit
    gridRef.current.api.setFocusedCell(0, firstColumnField);

    // Now, start editing the focused cell
    gridRef.current.api.startEditingCell({
      rowIndex: 0,
      colKey: firstColumnField,
      // Optional parameters for editing, like keyPress and charPress, can be added here
    });
  }
}, [editMode, gridRef.current, ppsColumns, lastSelected]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still requires me to click (only once rather than two times) on the cell so that I can start editing.

Comment: I think this is due to the asynchronous nature of rendering and state updates in React and ag-Grid. One approach to ensure that the grid is ready and to avoid the need for an initial click is to slightly delay the execution of the edit command.